# Bluetooth (rtl8723be) does not find devices on Lenovo Ideapad 100-14iby

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, lenovo, rtl8723be

I'm an Italian Xubuntu user and have a problem with Lenovo Ideapad 100-14iby.

Problem --> Bluetooth seems to work but does not find devices

I think the problem is the network card, RTL8723BE. About this I found [this post on github.io which provides a fix](https://infinitecoder.github.io/posts/2017-12-09-rtl8723be-fix/) (detailed below), but the Bluetooth still doesn't work.

I'll show you some commands from the terminal for better understanding of the situation.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b49f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:1169 Syntek Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg | grep Blue`:

```
[    4.431236] usb 2-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   14.771946] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   14.771982] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.771988] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.771992] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.771999] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   26.075947] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   26.075949] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   26.075956] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   42.875183] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   42.875197] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   42.875210] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

`hciconfig -a`

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 4C:BB:58:C0:6A:BA  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:3140 acl:0 sco:0 events:218 errors:0
    TX bytes:13203 acl:0 sco:0 commands:217 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'lenovone'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xb
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x8723
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

`dpkg -l | grep blue`:

```
ii  blueman                               2.1.2-1                               amd64        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluetooth                             5.53-0ubuntu3                         all          Bluetooth support
ii  bluez                                 5.53-0ubuntu3                         amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                            5.53-0ubuntu3                         amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-obexd                           5.53-0ubuntu3                         amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tools                           2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-2build1        amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                   5.53-0ubuntu3                         amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth           1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6                  amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg |grep usb`

```
[    0.650107] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.650125] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.650159] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.966164] pci 0000:00:1d.0: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x662 took 1952839 usecs
[    3.362271] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    3.362275] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.362277] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    3.362280] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-47-generic ehci_hcd
[    3.362282] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    3.364813] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    3.364817] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.364819] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
```

`usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.4.0-47-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.04
```

`dmesg | grep hci`:

```
[    3.342725] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    3.342734] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    3.343031] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    3.343043] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    3.343061] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    3.346989] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    3.347016] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0x90915000
[    3.361719] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    3.361977] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-47-generic ehci_hcd
[    3.362786] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    3.362817] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    3.362824] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
```

`lsmod | grep btusb`:

```
btusb                  57344  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
bluetooth             581632  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  16
ccm                    20480  3
cmac                   16384  4
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 24576  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      24576  1 intel_rapl_msr
intel_soc_dts_thermal    20480  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 intel_soc_dts_thermal
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
kvm                   663552  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   126976  1
punit_atom_debug       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
uvcvideo               98304  0
cryptd                 24576  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
mei_hdcp               24576  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
rtl8723be             102400  0
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
btcoexist             155648  1 rtl8723be
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
btusb                  57344  0
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723be
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
rtlwifi                90112  4 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,btcoexist,rtl8723_common
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
mac80211              843776  3 rtl_pci,rtl8723be,rtlwifi
btintel                24576  1 btusb
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
bluetooth             581632  41 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
i915                 1986560  5
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
cfg80211              704512  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
serio_raw              20480  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
rtsx_pci_ms            24576  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ideapad_laptop         20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
snd                    90112  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei_txe                28672  1
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_txe
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  6
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   491520  5 drm_kms_helper,i915
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
hid                   131072  2 usbhid,hid_generic
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         28672  0
psmouse               155648  0
r8169                  90112  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
realtek                24576  1
lpc_ich                24576  0
rtsx_pci               73728  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
ahci                   40960  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    32768  2 wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop
video                  49152  2 ideapad_laptop,i915
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0e)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB EHCI (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

These are the steps to fix provided by [the post I mentioned earlier](https://infinitecoder.github.io/posts/2017-12-09-rtl8723be-fix/):

Step 1 --> Fixing WiFi

**Creation of file rtl8723be.conf in /etc/modprobe.d**

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf 
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

Step 2 --> Fixing bluetooth

I made sure that TLP was installed

Proceeds ID bluetooth with **Command-->lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:b49f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Bluetooth Radio
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174f:1169 Syntek Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

ID is --> **`04f2:b49f`**

Modified file `tlp.conf` in my casa located in `/etc`
Change USB_BLACKLIST= "ID bluetooth card"

After all this Bluetooth does not work.

What else can I try?

Thanks

-----------Update 27/09/2020-------------

**Reply to Jeremy31**

`sudo awk -vRS= '/b49f/{print $0,"\n"}' /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices :`

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=04 Dev#=  5 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04f2 ProdID=b49f Rev= 2.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek 
S:  Product=Bluetooth Radio 
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:* #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   9 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   9 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 2 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  17 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  17 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 3 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  25 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  25 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 4 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  33 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  33 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 5 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  49 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=  49 Ivl=1ms
```

`dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; mokutil --sb-state:`

```
[    0.080805] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.118381] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.357886] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    3.306565] [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found
[    4.705027] usb 2-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   14.547360] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   14.547402] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.547409] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.547412] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.547419] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.581870] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[   27.285225] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   27.285228] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   27.285236] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   45.792935] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   45.792948] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   45.792968] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
EFI variables are not supported on this system
`
```

`modinfo btusb :`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
license:        GPL
version:        0.8
description:    Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.8
author:         Marcel Holtmann <marcel@holtmann.org>
firmware:       mediatek/mt7668pr2h.bin
firmware:       mediatek/mt7663pr2h.bin
srcversion:     808BE229E66F97547A76866
alias:          usb:v8087p0A5Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0930p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v413Cp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0A5Cp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v04CAp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0489p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0BB4p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v105Bp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v19FFp0239d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v413Cp8197d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0C10p0000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDBp1002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v044Ep3002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v044Ep3001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BFp030Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v057Cp3800d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8281d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp821Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp821Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp821Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8218d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8215d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8213d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A5Cp21E1d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp763Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icE0isc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dcE0dsc01dp04ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dcE0dsc01dp01ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          of:N*T*Cusb4ca,301aC*
alias:          of:N*T*Cusb4ca,301a
alias:          of:N*T*Cusbcf3,e300C*
alias:          of:N*T*Cusbcf3,e300
alias:          of:N*T*Cusb1286,204eC*
alias:          of:N*T*Cusb1286,204e
depends:        btrtl,btbcm,bluetooth,btintel
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           btusb
vermagic:       5.4.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        69:0F:B2:8C:24:82:6C:28:AB:28:F7:D2:E5:B8:D0:0B:2C:EF:1F:87
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      52:84:08:D7:E6:AF:FF:E3:97:A7:E1:F6:E3:EB:D4:34:EB:59:B4:2D:
        94:65:55:E8:CB:EC:40:EE:1A:7E:0C:7A:EC:F3:96:DB:E2:39:DD:02:
        27:60:02:0A:0E:AA:2F:46:94:35:9D:01:8F:7B:14:62:C2:BC:4B:21:
        42:73:0F:D9:78:86:F1:BC:3D:34:B9:6C:41:E5:06:93:A0:88:74:DB:
        CD:0A:14:F3:5E:71:33:F3:92:64:61:15:6F:A6:B7:41:D5:38:57:E2:
        20:EF:8C:90:A2:57:38:FE:54:10:44:9C:3E:B2:4D:B2:95:B8:8F:AF:
        63:BC:27:BD:DC:94:A8:BF:32:94:02:5B:F8:A9:11:2B:8C:CD:C1:BE:
        D4:2B:EE:8B:34:D5:2E:EA:9E:2F:2A:F3:42:66:5E:EF:8A:6F:86:5F:
        B7:1C:C3:C8:CE:0C:BE:F0:45:6D:0B:57:D2:1B:B3:BA:19:72:F1:78:
        02:B2:AB:97:9B:0A:27:36:15:20:26:AA:04:FA:58:45:C3:71:44:02:
        62:38:F4:81:67:F0:F3:8B:CF:0D:0F:1C:2C:4C:9E:AC:A4:E9:12:A6:
        8B:50:CB:1A:A0:C3:EA:34:F4:56:AF:EC:1D:A5:D0:78:1D:95:15:13:
        EE:C8:96:93:33:38:00:8B:E8:7D:8A:FB:50:19:67:2A:8B:CA:88:6C:
        B8:2A:1D:FA:FB:B5:3B:F6:AC:D3:CD:FC:E5:28:64:CF:DA:60:EC:FB:
        E3:BC:BD:70:2A:DF:30:42:C3:46:29:3F:F3:40:55:E0:E5:34:78:62:
        46:4A:4D:8D:71:56:32:7F:FF:40:BF:F0:2B:46:98:DB:B3:41:1D:43:
        15:15:1B:6D:36:33:B0:BF:D7:B4:12:79:2F:8E:2F:38:FF:39:BD:E1:
        58:2D:48:45:02:3C:3B:18:EA:97:17:CB:82:5F:14:96:D5:9F:55:66:
        E5:E3:B2:E2:BF:76:BC:DA:FF:4E:62:13:BB:9D:BD:37:8B:EF:D6:26:
        B7:66:90:8C:F8:E7:30:A4:2A:2F:3B:32:75:95:74:DF:BA:42:88:49:
        C8:3E:6B:98:C1:3A:3D:30:95:4C:D7:37:D0:9F:32:07:06:87:0F:55:
        DD:73:29:60:6E:AD:71:37:4B:88:A7:F7:B0:F2:C8:E1:FE:7B:5E:E8:
        13:EB:57:E2:A3:AA:43:F9:46:73:76:69:66:71:A7:AE:C5:1D:21:F4:
        B6:05:8B:10:F9:47:CA:52:41:BF:D7:D8:68:8D:24:B2:47:2A:AF:C4:
        97:D7:5D:E0:77:A8:FC:E3:F9:86:94:9E:EF:EB:F3:B5:74:4C:CB:DA:
        2F:4B:4D:23:D1:94:B4:A6:71:80:45:E3
parm:           disable_scofix:Disable fixup of wrong SCO buffer size (bool)
parm:           force_scofix:Force fixup of wrong SCO buffers size (bool)
parm:           enable_autosuspend:Enable USB autosuspend by default (bool)
parm:           reset:Send HCI reset command on initialization (bool)
```

Comment: What is the Xubuntu version?

Comment: The version is --> Xubuntu 20.04

Comment: What result for `sudo awk -vRS= '/b49f/{print $0,"\n"}' /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices`

Comment: You have 2 separate Bluetooth devices here. One that is built-in and part of wifi+BT rtl8723be chip inside your laptop, and a second external  BT device connected through USB, per your `lsusb` output. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I replyed you in the ask.

Comment: @BarBar1234 I know that in some cases BT devices are connected to USB ports internally ( i read it somewhere). I say this because i don't have an externally BT devices connected.  
I don't care which BT to use as long as it works , maybe it is better not to use the rtl8723be , if it is possibile .

Comment: Please edit to include result for `modinfo btusb`

Comment: @Jeremy31i replyed you in the ask

Comment: What about `dkms status` it seems my version isn't loaded

Comment: @Jeremy31 this is the output : 
btusb, 4.0, 5.4.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

Comment: Try `sudo rm /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko` Then do `sudo cp ~/bluetooth-5.4/btusb.ko /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko`  Then reboot and I will see if I can figure out what happened

Comment: @Jeremy31 outpur of command  ` sudo cp ~/bluetooth-5.4/btusb.ko /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko ` 
`cp: impossibile eseguire stat di '/home/beppe/bluetooth-5.4/btusb.ko': File o directory non esistente`

"Impossibile eseguire" means impossible to execute 
"File o directory non esistente" means File or directory no existing

Comment: do a `cd bluetooth-5.4 && make && sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko` then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 You are the best.The BT now works perfectly
Can you explain to me what happened?

Comment: I made a change to the kernel source code so that it will load firmware needed for the bluetooth

Comment: ok , but now I am using RTL8723BE or usb BT ?

Comment: The bluetooth is part of the PCIe RTL8723BE wifi on the USB bus.  I had to look at Windows driver files to confirm

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks so much , you have solved my issue so fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Secure Boot if the computer uses UEFI.  Then in terminal do

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.4.git
cd bluetooth-5.4
make
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
```

Reboot
Until I can figure out what is wrong with the dkms after a kernel update you will need to

```
cd bluetooth-5.4
make clean
make
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
```

Reboot

Comment: I made but no changes, the BT still doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit the question to include results for `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: Just done. Find everything at the bottom of the question

Comment: I don't think you will need to use the steps after a kernel update.  I think you must have gotten a kernel update before installing the driver using dkms and that is what the issue was as I had similar results