# Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBY Bluetooth not discover any device

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, lenovo

my system is Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBY. i turned ON bluetooth but it did not discover any device .

> **lspci -nn | grep Net**
> 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

```
sudo dpkg -i btusb-lp1708692-dkms_0.1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package btusb-lp1708692-dkms.
(Reading database ... 216621 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack btusb-lp1708692-dkms_0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking btusb-lp1708692-dkms (0.1) ...
Setting up btusb-lp1708692-dkms (0.1) ...
Loading new btusb-lp1708692-0.1 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.0-39-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.13.0-39-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): unable to determine source package for btusb-lp1708692-dkms
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/btusb-lp1708692/0.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package btusb-lp1708692-dkms (--install):
 installed btusb-lp1708692-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 btusb-lp1708692-dkms
vivek612@vivek612-Lenov
```

Comment: Hello. The error is pretty clear the bluetooth adapter did not get turned on in hardware. I see you are using kernel 5.13.0-39-generic. You do not mention a version of Ubuntu, you should. Maybe a newer kernel would work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.4.git
cd bluetooth-5.4
make
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
```

Reboot. Until I can figure out what is wrong with the dkms after a kernel update you will need to

```
cd bluetooth-5.4
make clean
make
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
```

Reboot.

Follow [Bluetooth (rtl8723be) does not find devices on Lenovo Ideapad 100-14iby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277459/bluetooth-rtl8723be-does-not-find-devices-on-lenovo-ideapad-100-14iby)