# Bluetooth doesn't discover headphones nor other devices - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: 22.04, headphones

I think i'm having some issues with my bluetooth driver.
The following commands were ran:

**hciconfig -a**

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: CC:47:40:81:CD:37  ACL MTU: 1021:6  SCO MTU: 255:12
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:8857 acl:0 sco:0 events:929 errors:0
    TX bytes:15739 acl:0 sco:0 commands:861 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xfd 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
    Name: '....'
    Class: 0x7c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Revision: 0xb
    LMP Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Subversion: 0x8852
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

**btmgmt info**

```
Index list with 1 item
hci0:   Primary controller
    addr CC:47:40:81:CD:37 version 11 manufacturer 93 class 0x7c010c
    supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr hs le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy static-addr phy-configuration 
    current settings: powered bondable ssp br/edr le secure-conn 
    name ...
    short name
```

**sudo dmesg | grep Blue**

```
[    1.439357] usb 3-2: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    2.466820] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.466856] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.466863] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.466866] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.466873] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.711766] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[    3.910378] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.910383] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.910387] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.961186] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[  124.898809] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  124.898818] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  124.898823] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  140.331849] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[  151.009819] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
[  847.176089] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[ 1010.620553] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[ 1241.507602] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[ 9991.967864] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
```

**mesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; mokutil --sb-state**

```
SecureBoot disabled 
Platform is in Setup Mode
```

**uname -r**

```
6.2.0-36-generic
```

The last thing I tried was from this link: [Bluetooth (rtl8723be) does not find devices on Lenovo Ideapad 100-14iby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277459/bluetooth-rtl8723be-does-not-find-devices-on-lenovo-ideapad-100-14iby)

However i got stuck here and i have not ideea how to proceed(noob here):
**make**

```
make -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-36-generic/build M=/home/.../bluetooth-5.4 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic'

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

make[1]: *** [Makefile:820: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
```

**L.T:** I've changed the direction a little bit and now i'm trying this:

https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be_bt#3-save-and-build
from here [Not finding bluetooth devices | Ubuntu 20.04.5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457815/not-finding-bluetooth-devices-ubuntu-20-04-5)

However now i have the following issue:

**sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic**

**make**

```
make -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-36-generic/build M=/home/.../new_attempt/rtl8852be_bt modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  You are using:           gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  CC [M]  /home/.../new_attempt/rtl8852be_bt/btusb.o
/home/.../new_attempt/rtl8852be_bt/btusb.c: In function ‘btusb_probe’:
/home/.../new_attempt/rtl8852be_bt/btusb.c:3819:13: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘prevent_wake’
 3819 |         hdev->prevent_wake = btusb_prevent_wake;
      |             ^~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:260: /home/.../new_attempt/rtl8852be_bt/btusb.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2026: /home/.../new_attempt/rtl8852be_bt] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:17: all] Error 2
```

Can anybody help me fix this somehow?
Note that in Ubuntu Cinnamon devices get discovered, especially my headphone and I can pair from either the command line or from some Bluetooth manager, but there is a lot of sound stuttering which is unplayable regardless of my "efforts" in trying to fix the problem from other available resources.
Please let me know if more information is needed.
Thanks!